# systemd: autofs containing autofs does not unmount

Tags: mount, systemd, autofs, automounting

I'm trying to set up two directories, each automounted:

- `/mnt/dir`
- `/mnt/dir/subdir`

In my case, these are:

- `/mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs` (read only)
- `/mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs/btrbk-snap` (RW for taking snapshots with [`btrbk`](https://github.com/digint/btrbk))

My `/etc/fstab` contains:

```
LABEL=rootfs    /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs               btrfs   ro,subvol=/,lazytime,compress=lzo,ssd,discard,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=2
LABEL=rootfs    /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs/btrbk-snap    btrfs   rw,subvol=/btrbk-snap,lazytime,compress=lzo,ssd,discard,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=2,x-systemd.requires-mounts-for=/mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs
```

I do:

```
svelte ~# systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart local-fs.target
svelte ~# mount | grep btrfs-vol/rootfs
systemd-1 on /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=2,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
```

Strangely, `/mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs`, is already mounted.

If I unmount `/mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs`, it is immediately remounted:

```
svelte ~# umount /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs
svelte ~# mount | grep btrfs-vol/rootfs
systemd-1 on /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=2,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
```

Now if I ping the subdirectory, it automounts:

```
svelte ~# (cd /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs/btrbk-snap/ && mount | grep btrfs-vol/rootfs)
systemd-1 on /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=2,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
/dev/mapper/vg_svelte-rootfs on /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs type btrfs (ro,relatime,lazytime,compress=lzo,ssd,discard,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
```

Note that the `fstype` of `/dev/mapper/vg_svelte-rootfs` has changed from `autofs` to `btrfs`.

A few seconds later (I have `timeout=2` for testing`):

```
svelte ~# mount | grep btrfs-vol/rootfssystemd-1 on /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=2,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
```

The subdirectory is unmounted, and the `fstype` of `/dev/mapper/vg_svelte-rootfs` reverts to `autofs`, *but it stays mounted*.

**How do I get it to automatically unmount?**

---

Possibly useful information:

`journal` output:

```
Feb 21 17:16:07 svelte systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb 21 17:16:23 svelte systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs...
Feb 21 17:16:23 svelte systemd[1]: Set up automount mnt-btrfs\x2dvol-home-btrbk\x2dsnap.automount.
Feb 21 17:16:23 svelte systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs.
Feb 21 17:16:23 svelte systemd[1]: mnt-btrfs\x2dvol-rootfs-btrbk\x2dsnap.automount: Directory /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs/btrbk-snap to mount over is not empty, mounting anyway.
Feb 21 17:16:23 svelte systemd[1]: Set up automount mnt-btrfs\x2dvol-rootfs-btrbk\x2dsnap.automount.
Feb 21 17:16:23 svelte systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems.
Feb 21 17:16:25 svelte systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems.
Feb 21 17:16:25 svelte systemd[1]: Unset automount mnt-btrfs\x2dvol-rootfs-btrbk\x2dsnap.automount.
Feb 21 17:16:25 svelte systemd[1]: Unmounting /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs...
Feb 21 17:16:25 svelte systemd[1]: Unmounted /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs.
Feb 21 17:17:44 svelte systemd[1]: Unset automount mnt-btrfs\x2dvol-home-btrbk\x2dsnap.automount.
```

Checking that nothing has the directory open:

```
svelte ~# lsof /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
svelte ~[2]# ls -l /run/user/1000 | grep gvfs
ls: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
d????????? ? ?    ?      ?            ? gvfs
```

I've never seen `?` where I'd expect the `rwx` placehoders to be before.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get mounts to automatically unmount with `x-systemd.idletimeout=2` in Debian Stretch with no luck. Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: @maulinglawns I've suggested an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at fstab `systemd` option [`x-systemd.requires-mounts-for=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#x-systemd.requires-mounts-for=):

> Configures a `RequiresMountsFor=` dependency between the created mount unit and other mount units. The argument must be an absolute path. This option may be specified more than once. See `RequiresMountsFor=` in `systemd.unit(5)` for details.